# Does WebSphere Liberty store it's process ID (pid) anywhere on Linux?

Tags: linux, websphere

When a [WebSphere Liberty](https://www.ibmdw.net/wasdev/docs/introducing_the_liberty_profile/) server is started on Linux, is its pid stored anywhere on the filesystem, in a .pid file or similar? I'm developing an automated script that under some scenarios, when the server won't cleanly stop, needs to force-kill it.

Comment: is this under Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi on Linux server there is .pid directory which will have PID

For example :

```
/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/servers # cd .pid

/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/servers/.pid # ls -lp

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6 Apr  7 11:05 defaultServer.pid

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6 Apr  7 11:10 test1.pid

/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/servers/.pid # cat defaultServer.pid

14088

/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/servers/.pid #
```

NOTE : On windows there is no PID file/directory created.

VS, opinions are my own and not those of my employer

Comment: Just verified that, this seems to work - thank you!